# substracting dataframe columns with different granularity on datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

I have some price data (such as from yahoo finance) with a daily granularity datetime variable as index, lets call that df and lets say its the microsoft closing price as value variable. To get the monthly average closing price I can obviously do one of these two:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
df = yf.download("CMG", start="2012-01-01",end="2020-01-01" )
dfm = df.resample("M").mean()
dfm2 = df.groupby(df.index.to_period("M")).mean()
```

To me they look very similar only difference I can tell is that on the resample the new datetime index is the end of the month and the groupby to_period will have an index of yyyy-mm.

I now want to add a column to df with daily granularity that has for each daily closing price the deviation from its monthly mean. So 1/jan/2020 - mean(jan-20), 2/jan/2020 - mean(jan-20), 1/feb/2020 - mean(feb-20).

Because dfm and df have different indices I cannot just do df-dfm.

The only thing I can come up with is loop through df, put a counter on dfm and put an if statement in the loop, very much a c-type approach but not very pythonic. I guess it would look sth like this (but this didn't work):

```
counter = 0
df["dailyminusmonthly"] =""

for i in df:
if i.index <= dfm[counter].index:
    i.dailyminusmonthly = i.close - dfm.close[counter]
else:
    counter = counter +1
    i.dailyminusmonthly = i.close - dfm.close[counter]
```

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `DatetimeIndex` to monthly period, so you can subtract `dfm2`, only then is necessary convert to numpy array, because index of subtracted `Series` is different like original `df` for prevent full `NaN`s column:

```
df['dailyminusmonthly1']= (df['Close'].to_period('M')
                                    .sub(df.groupby(df.index.to_period("M"))['Close'].mean())
                                    .to_numpy())
```

Another simplier solution is use [`Resampler.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.transform.html) with same index like original:

```
df['dailyminusmonthly2']= df['Close'].sub(df.resample("M")['Close'].transform('mean'))
```

---

```
print (df)
                  Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close  \
Date                                                                     
2012-01-03  343.700012  350.489990  340.000000  341.269989  341.269989   
2012-01-04  346.000000  349.980011  345.010010  348.750000  348.750000   
2012-01-05  346.880005  351.980011  342.570007  350.480011  350.480011   
2012-01-06  348.880005  352.630005  347.350006  348.950012  348.950012   
2012-01-09  349.000000  349.489990  336.290009  339.739990  339.739990   
               ...         ...         ...         ...         ...   
2019-12-24  827.099976  829.409973  823.159973  828.890015  828.890015   
2019-12-26  829.409973  839.280029  828.239990  838.599976  838.599976   
2019-12-27  839.969971  840.000000  835.000000  836.789978  836.789978   
2019-12-30  838.169983  838.750000  829.010010  836.070007  836.070007   
2019-12-31  837.239990  842.270020  833.359985  837.109985  837.109985   

            Volume  dailyminusmonthly1  dailyminusmonthly2  
Date                                                        
2012-01-03  728100          -13.559013          -13.559013  
2012-01-04  743100           -6.079002           -6.079002  
2012-01-05  672300           -4.348991           -4.348991  
2012-01-06  370700           -5.878990           -5.878990  
2012-01-09  748600          -15.089012          -15.089012  
           ...                 ...                 ...  
2019-12-24   91900            3.640494            3.640494  
2019-12-26  255400           13.350455           13.350455  
2019-12-27  201900           11.540458           11.540458  
2019-12-30  211400           10.820487           10.820487  
2019-12-31  282200           11.860465           11.860465  

[2012 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: thank you and sorry for the messy question, I m new to python

Comment: @nik - I think question good, only missed mcve, you are welcome ;) Happy coding ;)